# Configure Sitecore Forms to use different environment connection string in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore-forms, connectionstring

How to add configure Sitecore Forms in development environment to use different environment connection string to debug the stage environment issue.

I have modified `ConnectionString.config` file and pointed web, core, security and experienceForms connection string to use stage environment database to debug the issue in development machine. Even after pointing development machine to stage environment DB, the Sitecore forms in loading content from Dev database.

May I know, Are there any other configurations for Sitecore forms?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you means forms on the page, when they are rendered as form components? Or forms in Sitecore Forms application loaded from Sitecore Launchpad? Sitecore Forms application uses indexes to load content so you would need to rebuild master index (or at least reinded forms part of the tree)

Comment: You need to update the Solr path in your connection string to point to the stage environment.

Comment: Yes  Sitecore Forms Content on the page is rendering from Dev database even after pointing to stage db. @MarekMusielak

Comment: @SumitBhatia, May I know How solr is useful for Sitecore Forms? Does Sitecore forms get index in Solr?

Comment: @KumariDimple Yes if you create any form and then Sitecore retrieves the information using the index. So try this and check.

Comment: Can you try rebuilding sitecore_master_index? Also sitecore_masrketingdefinitions_master and sitecore_marketing-asset_index_master

Comment: I have observed that Sitecore Forms rendering content from Master database not from web database. How to configure it to render published content? in SiteDefinition.Config file I have configure database context as web. @GauravAgarwal

Answer (score 0):

In order to stage environment database, you need to do the following -

1. Need to update your connection string to point to the stage environment.
2. Rebuild `master index, siteore_marketingdefinitions_master and sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master`
   Follow this blog for this - https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/06/06/unable-to-see-the-newly-created-sitecore-forms/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to see the forms after updating your `ConnectionString.config`, you can try the following steps to make it work.

- Clear browser cache
- Clear Sitecore cache `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`
- Rebuilt the Forms folder from the Developer menu, like this.

[image]

- Open your site in the Incognito/private mode.
- Finally, if anything doesn't work, Rebuilt your `Sitecore Master Index`

Hope this will solve your issue.

Thanks